# How can I force Internet Download Manager to intercept Mega's downlod process?

Tags: download-manager, web-hosting, file-download

I want to download a file from Mega through my own download manager not Mega's download manager. I tried many times with available options in Internet Download Manager and can't get Internet Download Manger to intercept the Mega's download process. [image]

Comment: I doubt this would be possible without alterations to IDM itself. Mega downloads an encrypted file and decrypts it clientside, even if you could intercept the download you'd only get garbage without specific support for then decoding.

Comment: @mms911 - You can't Mega uses a client side mechanic ( Javascript ) to decrypt the file so it can be downloaded.  The good news Mega has an SDK that will allow the authors of your download manager to add support for Mega's cloud storage service.

Answer (score 1):

First of all Download Mega Downloader and Install on your PC from the link here: [Download Mega.nz files with IDM](https://megadownloaderapp.com/download-mega-files-idm-directly/)

After that go to configuration settings from the options menu and enalbe Streaming Server option and save the settings.

Once it is done, All you do is click on Streaming from the options and paste the Mega URL that you wish to download via IDM

and then you'll get a streaming URL from the software. Copy that link and paste in IDM, You're done. You can download the mega.nz file using IDM with pause/resume capabilities.

Comment: this is not working anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Use Mega Downloader.

1. Download Mega Downloader v1.7 and install it.
2. Open Options->Configuration->Streaming
3. Check "Use streaming server."
4. Save and close.
5. Click on Streaming->Manage Library
6. Multimedia Library will open in your default browser.
7. Click on Import.
8. After that copy the link from which u want to download and paste it in the dialog box.
9. After that click on Import.
10. Now Streaming->See Library
11. Now you will find your desired file to download.
12. Click on it and Download Video.
13. IDM will pop up.